# Download dataset directly from Kaggle to GoogleColab

Tags: google-colaboratory, kaggle

I am following this tutorial https://www.kaggle.com/general/74235 to download the dataset directly from Kaggle to Google Colab. However, these 3 lines of code really make me struggle in understanding the structure of files in Colab.
[image]

What did I do wrong and if I was wrong, what is the suitable way to download the dataset directly from Kaggle.

Answer (score 0):

Colab doesn't remember where you are between commands. Try putting all the commands on a single line using `&&`. This might not work exactly for you since I don't have your exact environment.

```
!mkdir ~/.kaggle/ && cp kaggle.json ~/.kaggle/ && chmod 600 ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json
```